# Eclipse CoreException Location

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I am attempting to use the `ILaunchManager#getLaunchConfigurations` method from the Eclipse `org.eclipse.debug.core` package, but the compiler is giving me the message:

`The method getLaunchConfigurations() from the type ILaunchManager refers to the missing type CoreException`

I can see that `getLaunchConfigurations()` throws the `CoreException` exception, but I just cannot find the jar that contains the `CoreException` class! Does anyone know which jar I need to use to resolve this problem?

The code that I'm using is:

```
ILaunchManager launchManager = DebugPlugin.getDefault().getLaunchManager();
for (ILaunchConfiguration launchConfiguration : launchManager.getLaunchConfigurations()) {
  String configName = launchConfiguration.getName();
}
```

I've included the following jars in the build path:

```
  org.eclipse.debug.core_3.7.100.v20120521-2012
  org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.8.0.v20120521-2346
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some useful sites when you're facing such an issue are: http://findjar.com and http://grepcode.com

The following page has the search results: http://grepcode.com/search?query=org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException&n=

You'll need `org.eclipse.equinox.common.VERSION.jar`.